# URL SEO for e-commerce website products

Tags: url, seo, e-commerce, search-engine

I'm currently working out the best setup for URLs on an e-commerce site I'm working on.

The site sells games and as you may already know games can come with demos and multiple dlc packs. On the site a game, a demo and dlc all have their own individual pages.

I have designed the following urls... but can't figure out which one is better and whether potentially they might be too long.

Option One:

```
.../product/the-game-name/                       // the full game
.../product/the-game-name/demo/                  // the demo
.../product/the-game-name/dlc/name-of-dlc/       // the specific dlc
```

Option Two:

```
.../game/the-game-name/                  // the full game
.../demo/the-game-name/                  // the demo
.../dlc/the-game-name/name-of-dlc/       // the specific dlc
```

In both examples "..." is purely the domain name: i.e. http://mysite.com

If anyone can tell me the pros and cons of either option, or whether there are better alternatives that would be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always been told that you want your key phrase rich URLs as close to the root as possible.  To use hyperbole, domain.com/manufacturers/nintendo/products/super-mario-brothers is less effective than domain.com/super-mario-brothers or domain.com/nintendo/super-mario-brothers.

With the slashes, I assume you have IIS7.  If you don't, you can download the [Rewrite Module 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/web/spotlight/urlrewriter/), and once installed, click it, then click add rule, there's a module right on the interface for taking care of **trailing slashes** throughout your solution.

After you've downloaded the Rewrite module, I would also recommend the [Search Engine Optimization Toolkit](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/12/15/search-engine-optimization-seo-toolkit.aspx) that will offer suggestions as well.  Some of the suggestions may be feeble, but some may be worth looking at.  For instance, maybe you have your pageheaders styled a certain way but you don't have h1 tags, which SEs like.

Lastly, none of the rewrite modules mean anything if you don't get your hands dirty and go out there and make backlinks.  Submit your sitemap.xml to google, your urllist.txt to yahoo/bing, and then backlink.  Put your site in as many free directories as possible if they're relevant to your industry -- don't "link farm", though.  Make a notepad file with a 30 or 40 word description with key phrases from your site, and just copy/paste 'em into backlinking directories.  The most important backlinks are the ones that are pertinent to your product.

Comment: Nice and in-depth. I will checkout the SEO toolkit you've recommended.

Comment: The tool is quite handy although some of the reports are incorrect - its complaining about not having a description meta tag available in a few pages... but when I manually look at those pages I can see one. So not sure what's happening there. It tends to change each time I run the test as well and doesn't say it for all pages... even though its the same header.inc.php file.

Comment: Yes, you'll see minor gaffes here and there, but I think it offers a pretty good generalization over overall site "pre"health -- "pre" meaning if it's good to go to get ready for backlinking, which will be your ticket to true health.  And when I say backlinking, I'm not talking about cheap link farms, and all that.  You're going to try to get as many QUALITY, RELEVANT backlinks as you can from related industries, and respected directories such as dmoz.org.  And don't try to trick SEs with CSS tricks, hidden text, etc., they're picking up on all that and they'll penalize you if caught.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid extending the URL with things like /product/ if possible. It doesn't really add anything.

Otherwise, I prefer the first option as it seems more natural.

You may also want to be consistent with using folders (ends with a slash) or files, don't mix.

.../the-game-name/                       # the full game

.../the-game-name/demo/                    # the demo

.../the-game-name/dlc/name-of-dlc/         # the specific dlc

Your use of dashes for spaces is good.

Comment: Ah yes... the lack of slashes at the end of the urls is a typo... they should all have them... I'll add them in. Cheers for the feedback. As for the product... I'm using a framework so product would be the controller. Therefore its required in case the game name is actually the name of another controller on the website... unlikely I know but always a possibility.

Comment: Would it make sense to change "product" to the name of the controller then?

Comment: Yes... in this example the name of the controller is "product".

Comment: Hey Diggers ... I don't believe that the lack of trailing slashes is a typo and that they should all have 'em.  The important thing here is they either they ALL have trailing slashes, or they all do NOT have trailing slashes.  Either way is fine, as long as you're consistent throughout.  If both domain.com/products and domain.com/products/ work, then you have a duplicate products issues.  So you just gotta choose one or the other, and the IIS7 rewrite tool allows for both options (your choice).  So trailing slashes are fine to include or omit, as long as you're consistent and don't use both!